# Me el siguiente error saleWarning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move

Tags: php, imagen

Estoy creando una interfaz en el que pueda subir los datos de un producto dentro de una base de datos en xampp, también estoy intentando añadir la dirección de la imagen, sin embargo me sale error cuando intento enviar los datos, se guardan bien, incluso la dirección de la imagen a la que debería de ser guardada, sin embargo me sale el error y la avisa de que la imagen no se ha movido.

aqui el codigo

```
<?php 
require 'conexionproduct.php';

$producto=$_POST['nombreproduct'];
$categ=$_POST['categoria'];
$subcateg=$_POST['subcategoria'];
$prec=$_POST['precio'];
$stoc=$_POST['stock'];
$descrip=$_POST['descripcion'];
$imagen='';
if(isset($_FILES["imagenproduct"])){
    $file=$_FILES["imagenproduct"];
    $nombre=$file["name"];
    $tipo=$file["type"];
    $ruta_provisional=$file["tmp_name"];
    $size=$file["size"];
    $dimensiones=getimagesize($ruta_provisional);
    $witdh = $dimensiones[0];
    $height = $dimensiones[1];
    $carpeta = "images/";
    if($tipo != 'image/jpg' && $tipo != 'image/JPG' && $tipo != 'image/jpeg'
    && $tipo != 'image/png' && $tipo != 'image/gif'){
        echo "El archivo no es una imagen";
    }else if ($size > 3*1024*1024){
        echo "Error: Imagen muy grande";
    }else{ 
        $src = $carpeta.$nombre;
        move_uploaded_file($ruta_provisional, $src);
        $imagen="images/".$nombre;
    }
}

$query=mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO producto (id_categoria,nom_produc,precio,stock,descripcion,id_subcategoria,foto) VALUES ('$categ','$producto','$prec','$stoc','$descrip','$subcateg','$imagen')");
```

?>

[image: Imagen del error]

Comment: Será que tienes que crear la carpeta primero o al menos comprobar si existe en la ruta que le has puesto

Comment: La carpeta si esta creada, intente crear otras nuevas pero nada funciona

Comment: Según el error la carpeta es: `/images/`.  Fíjate que parte de la raíz, es decir, la barra inicial `/` indica la raíz de tu disco duro, o la raíz de tu web, pero quizás debas cambiar esto: `$carpeta = "images/";` por esto: `$carpeta = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/';` a ver si cuela mejor, pues le agregará la ruta de tu disco completa de forma unívoca y quizás así te llegue a funcionar bien.